# @Async in spring mvc working without a Future return type?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

Sometimes when I am using @Async without return type of Future it returns null but sometimes it returns String. In documentation it is mentioned that return type of Future is must. I am confused why this is happening?

e.g.this one is working

```
@Service
public class MyClass implements MyClass2{

  @Async
  @Override
  public String getString() {

    return "hello";
  }
}
```

Comment: Not an error but it returns null. But sometimes the String is returned. I have used XML configuration to enable @Aysnc <task:annotation-driven />. Is this possible that the function may not be working async.

Comment: The @Async makes your method asynchronous so if the function finishes fast enough it will return the string value, but if not your value would be null (i,e, nothing has been returned). There doesn't seem to be a problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Please **don't** return a `String` from an `@Async` method. This is against the intentions of the makers. Excerpt from the [Spring Execution & Scheduling docu](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html):

> Even methods that return a value can be invoked asynchronously. However, such methods are required to have a Future typed return value. This still provides the benefit of asynchronous execution so that the caller can perform other tasks prior to calling get() on that Future.

**If your asynchronous method has a return type, it MUST be a Future object!**

Why? Because otherwise the method invoker won't be able to wait for the completion of the Thread that has handled the @Async method. The waiting for Thread-completion is handled by [Future.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())